# using aggregate function in codeigniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I am trying to write this below query in codeigniter format and getting some problem with the aggregate function:

```
$stmt = "select sum(subscription_amt) as samt, bill_month, 
                sum(loan_refund_amt*no_of_loan_installment+error_amt) as lamt 
         from pf_bill_det 
         where trim(pf_number)='$pfno' 
               and fin_year='$fyear' 
               and aproved='Y' group by bill_month";
$query = $this->db->query($stmt);
```

This query ending up with an error `loan_refund_amt*no_of_loan_installment+error_amt is not a column`. Please help me how to write this query using codeigniter query format.

Comment: try `$this->db->count();` count function in codeigniter...

Comment: make sure you have these columns `loan_refund_amt*no_of_loan_installment+error_amt` in your table or try with `loan_refund_amt * no_of_loan_installment + error_amt`

Comment: check you tables column which you use in query or show you tables columns here

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try this

```
$this->db->select("COUNT(*) AS MyCount");
$this->db->from("MyTable");
$this->db->where("field", $value);
$this->db->get();
```

**OR**

```
$this->db->select("SUM(field_name) AS MySum");
$this->db->from("MyTable");
$this->db->where("field", $value);
$this->db->get();
```

**OR**

```
$this->db->select("SUM(field_name) AS MySum, username, password");
$this->db->from("MyTable");
$this->db->where("field", $value);
$this->db->get();
```

**BUT**

In simple query function you can use

`$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(field_name) AS total_names, fname");`

`$query->result(); \\ Returns an array of objects`

`$query->result_array(); \\ Returns result as a pure array`

`$query->row(); \\ Returns a single result and first row`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$query=$this->db->query("select sum(subscription_amt) as samt,bill_month,sum(`loan_refund_amt`*`no_of_loan_installment`+`error_amt`) as lamt from pf_bill_det where trim(pf_number)='$pfno' and fin_year='$fyear' and aproved='Y' group by bill_month");
```